# Gmail sending with attachment in Django

Tags: html, django

I am trying to send Gmail with attachments also in Django.

here my **views.py**:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = EmailForm()
        context = {'email_form': form}
        return render(request, 'app/index.html', context)

    form = EmailForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        attach = request.FILES['attach']
        try:
            mail = EmailMessage(subject, message, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, [email])
            mail.attach_file(attach.name, attach.read(), attach.content_type)
            mail.send()
            context = {'message': 'email sended'}
            print("email sended")
            return render(request, 'app/email_template.html', context)
        except:
            context = {'message': 'Either the attachment is too  big or corrupt'}
            print("Either the attachment is too  big or corrupt")
            return render(request, 'app/index.html', context)
        context = {'message': 'Unable to send email. Please try again later'}
        return render(request, 'app/index.html', context)
```

**forms.py**:

```
class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    attach = forms.Field(widget = forms.FileInput)
    message = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
```

**template**:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-xl-4">
        <h1>Welcome in django's world</h1>

        {{message}}

        <form method="POST" action ="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <br></br>
        {{email_form.as_p}}

        <label>&nbsp;</label><label>&nbsp;</label><label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type ="submit"  name = "send" value = "Send"/>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Now each and every time I tried to sent mail, it shows `Either the attachment is too big or corrupt`, which means it goes by the `except:` block, instead of the try block.I just print the exception msg, it says

```
__init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Now how can I solve this problem such that Gmail will be sent successfully?

Comment: what does expectation prints  --> except Exception as e:  print(e.args)

Comment: @c.grey I just want to send Gmail successfully.

Comment: Yes, but you need to tell what Django exception you are getting

Comment: Have you enabled email sending in Gmail? You have to give permissions to third party app. As @c.grey mentioned replace except with except Exception as e: print(e) will help  you a lot

Comment: @KanchonGharami can you please print your exception as paste it

Comment: yeah I also add Less secure app access from google settings....now I just print the exception msg, it says **__init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 5 were given**

Comment: EmailMessage is imported directly from Django as "from django.core.mail import EmailMessage" or is it something custom made? If it is Custom made, please share the code for EmailMessage

Comment: I have imported directly **EmailMessage** by the following code in views.py:
`from email.message import EmailMessage`

Comment: @KanchonGharami Try replacing the import with this statement .. "from django.core.mail import EmailMessage"

Comment: and also pass the parameters appropriately .. here is the link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#the-emailmessage-class